# Putting variables to a power in python - Pythagorean theorem

Tags: python-3.x

I just started out with python and I was attempting to make a simple program to find the hypotenuse of a triangle for me. The code I tried using is as follows -

```
import math
print("what are sides of triangle")
a = input("a = ")
b = input("b = ")
print("the hypotenuse is ")
c = math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)  #<==Vs code says it stops working here
print(c)
```

how would I get this to work?

Comment: Use Pycharm editor. It's great for beginners. Without knowing the actual error, it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `input` returns a string, and you can't do arithmetic with a string.  Thus, you need to convert the result to a integer, using the `int(input("..."))`.

```
import math
print("what are sides of triangle")
a = int(input("a = "))
b = int(input("b = "))
print("the hypotenuse is ")
c = math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)  #<==Vs code says it stops working here
print(c)
```

Sample output:

```
what are sides of triangle
a = 3
b = 4
the hypotenuse is 
5.0
```